# Adding a random coefficient for an interaction term in a GLMM using lmer() in R

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to build a model with nested random effects and a random coefficient for an
interaction term using `lmer()` in R.

As seen in the created data below, I have a binary Response and two explanatory variables.
Time is continuous and Binary is a factor.  These data are taken from 6 individuals (AAA:FFF)
in three StudyAreas (CO, UT,MT).  Because individuals only occur at one StudyArea, IndID is
nested within StudyArea.

```
#Make data
Response <- as.factor(round(runif(150, 0, 1)))
Time <- round(runif(150, 2,50))
Binary <- round(runif(150, 0, 1))
IndID <- as.factor(rep(c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF"),25))
StudyArea <- as.factor(rep(c("CO", "UT", "MT"),50))

 Data <- data.frame(Response, Time, Binary, IndID, StudyArea)
 head(Data) 

    > head(Data) 
  Response Time Binary IndID StudyArea
1        0   44      1   AAA        CO
2        1   16      0   BBB        UT
3        1   43      0   CCC        MT
4        0   13      1   DDD        CO
5        0   34      1   EEE        UT
6        1   10      1   FFF        MT
```

Because I want to account for the difference across IndID and also StudyArea I have included both terms 
as random effects with adjustments to the intercept in the model below.

```
 require(lme4)
lmer1 <- lmer(Response ~ Time + Binary + (1|StudyArea) + (1|IndID), data=Data, family=binomial)
summary(lmer1)
```

Lets say that within a GLM structure the interaction between Time and StudyArea (i.e. (Time*StudyArea))
is a significant term.  Thus, in addition to the adjustments to the intercept, I also need an adjustment 
to the slope to account for differences in Time as a function of StudyArea.

While I have seen a number of examples in the Bates book (http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/Ch4.pdf)
and other posts for adding a random coef, I have not seen a rand coef for an interaction term.

From what I have gleaned from other posts the model structure should look something like the model 
below, but I look forward to the feedback and suggestions of others.  This code will fit a model,
although I am not sure it is correct theoretically

```
lmer2 <- lmer(Response ~ Time + Binary + (0+Time|StudyArea) + (1|StudyArea) + (1|IndID), data=Data, family=binomial)
```

Note: These are made up data and the results/p-values are obviously meaningless.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make the question more precise? At the moment it just seems to be "is this right?", and as such this question is more appropriate for `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` than StackOverflow.

Comment: Comments: (1) `(Time|StudyArea)` does represent an interaction between time and study area; (2) it's best not to separate the slope and intercept into independent terms `(1|StudyArea)+(0+Time|StudyArea)` unless you have to; (3) you're going to have lots of trouble fitting random effects with `n=3` and `n=6` respectively ...

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I will subscribe to the link you suggested for future lme4 questions. In my real data I have n=3 StudyAreas and n=25 individuals. While I think the number of individuals is sufficient for a random effect, I am unsure I have sufficient data for StudyAreas.  Taking your advice it seems that the model lmer(Response ~ Time + Binary + (Time|StudyArea) + (1|IndID), data=Data, family=binomial) will account for the intercept adjustments of StudyArea and IndID and also the interaction between StudyArea and Time.

Comment: I would definitely treat `StudyArea` as fixed, hence you want `Binary + Time*StudyArea + (1|indID)`

Comment: Cheers and thanks. I will look to r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org for more details as well.